# Outlook: Include attachments in reply (like with forward)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I receive an e-mail with attachments and I forward it, then Outlook includes the attachments.

Is this also possible with replies?

BTW: I don't want to have the original message attached as an attachment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a default setting of Outlook to minimise unwanted sending of attachments. usually if you receive an e-mail with an attachment there is no need to reply with the attachment still attached. From the early days of Outlook this feature was implemented to save repeated downloading and storing of attachments, thus cutting down on wasted bandwidth and unneccesary storage.

However it seems this can't be disabled. There is the [Reply All With Attachment](http://replyallwithattach.codeplex.com/) Add-on for Outlook 2010 & 2007 which might help you out.

Comment: @kcotreau - Its what they're for. Its nothing personal, was just such an obvious thing.

Comment: @kcotreau - I said -1 at the start of my comment, thats how you knew it was me, where's the anonymity in that. Just leaving a -1 and no comment would have been the cowardly way. Positive and negative votes are what keeps quality answers rising to the top and keeping incorrect answers down. Don't be so over protective of your reputation points, a down vote here and there keeps us on our toes to provide better answers for the people who rely on them.

Answer (score 3):

what is generally do is that i click the fwd button, replace the to address to what i want.

generally, i dont care about the "FWD: " but go ahead replace the "FWD: " with "RE: "

ps> i hate add-ons for those *the little* extra functionality... :)

Comment: I also steer clear of add ons. But as it jumped down my throat on Google I thought I'd throw it in. You can also Macro the button in yourself but as someone has done it for you.........

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook 2013 (I'm not sure about other versions as I don't have access to it), you can drag the attachment from the original email to the reply email that you are composing. The key point is, you need to open the reply email into a separate window by the "Pop Out" button. Then you can drag the attachment across these two windows and keep the attachment in reply.